# Kentico custom table query and / or combination

Tags: kentico

I have a custom table in Kentico 10. Some of the records have null latitude and longitude. I'm trying to exclude those rows while maintaining the existing where search on suburb, state, postcode. The current combination of the And / Or's isn't working. Is there a suggested, better way?

```
var locationsQuery = CustomTableItemProvider.GetItems("customtable.ProjectName_PostcodeSuburb")
                                            .WhereNotNull("Latitude")
                                            .And()
                                            .WhereNotNull("Longitude")
                                            .And()
                                            .WhereLike("Suburb", locationLike)
                                            .Or()
                                            .WhereLike("Postcode", locationLike)
                                            .Or()
                                            .WhereLike("State", locationLike)
                                            .Or()
                                            .WhereLike("Suburb + ', ' + State + ', ' + Postcode", locationLike)
                                            .Columns("Suburb, State, Postcode")
                                            .OrderBy("Suburb, State, Postcode")
                                            .TopN(20);
```

I also tried passing as parameters which seemed to work but worried about SQL injection and not sure how to pass as SQL parameters.

```
string whereSql = string.Format("Latitude IS NOT NULL AND Longitude IS NOT NULL AND ( Suburb LIKE '{0}' OR Postcode LIKE '{0}' OR State LIKE '{0}' )", locationLike);
var locationsQuery = CustomTableItemProvider.GetItems("customtable.ClearView_PostcodeSuburb",  whereSql, "Suburb, State, Postcode", 20, "Suburb, State, Postcode");
```

Answer (score 2):

Found solution, not very easy to find in documentation. Needed to created a WhereCondition and pass that as where in query.

```
var localityWhereCondition = new WhereCondition().WhereLike("Suburb", locationLike)
               .Or()
               .WhereLike("Postcode", locationLike)
               .Or()
               .WhereLike("State", locationLike)
               .Or()
               .WhereLike("Suburb + ', ' + State + ', ' + Postcode", locationLike);

var locationsQuery = CustomTableItemProvider.GetItems("customtable.ProjectName_PostcodeSuburb")
               .WhereNotNull("Latitude")
               .And()
               .WhereNotNull("Longitude")
               .And()
               .Where(localityWhereCondition)
               .Columns("Suburb, State, Postcode")
               .OrderBy("Suburb, State, Postcode")
               .TopN(20);
```

Comment: Hi. May I ask you to submit the feedback on documentation through the [feedback link](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/retrieving-database-data-using-objectquery-api#feedback-link) ? The link can be found at the bottom of every documentation page. Please tell us what keywords have you used during the search, on which page you have eventually found the solution, and/or what part exactly you had to figure out yourself. Thank you, we really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the entire gist of how to access it  here - https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/retrieving-database-data-using-objectquery-api

Reference Snapshot from the same page.

```
WhereEquals("ColumnName", value) - checks the equality of the value in the specified column with the value specified in the second parameter.
WhereGreaterThan("ColumnName", value) - compares the value in the specified column with the second parameter.
WhereNull("ColumnName") - select only rows where the specified column has a NULL value.
WhereNot(whereCondition) - negates the specified where condition.
WhereStartsWith("ColumnName", "Value") - only works for text columns. Selects only rows whose value in the specified column starts with the given value.
```